# android: can I find view by its text?

Tags: android

In my program I have dynamic buttons each representing a letter and I need to find a button that 
has a specific letter. Since the buttons' text change from time to time, I cannot use findViewById method, instead i need a way of finding view by its text. Is there one?

If not, suppose the button that has the letter I am searching for has id = B12 and I can get the number 12 in my program. How do I convert number 12 into R.id.B12 ?

Comment: what changes the text of your buttons? Probably it is your app, so just remember what values you put to your buttons and use those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for "find resource by name" functionality

```
String mButtonName = "button" + 12;
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mButtonName , "id", getPackageName());
```

That's the way you get in int(id) from string, but you can do the same using reflection which is supposed to be way faster.

```
public static int getId(String resourceName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resourceName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("No resource ID found for: "
            + variableName + " / " + c, e);
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
getId("button" + 12, R.id.class);
```

Hope it Helps!

Regards!